# Unable to load bundled css in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, mono, monodevelop

I have a ASP.NET MVC project created with MonoDevelop 5.7 on a Linux machine using latest `mono`.

I have a `_Layout.cshtml` that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/bundle/bootstrap")
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <b><a href="/" class="navbar-brand">EOS</a></b>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="xml">XML</a></li>
                        <li><a id="toCheckList" href="checklist">Checklist</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main role="main">
            <div ng-view class="cont-main"></div>
    </main>

    @RenderBody()

    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And a `BundleConfig.cs` that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace Angular2 {
    public class BundleConfig {

        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add (new StyleBundle ("~/bundle/bootstrap").IncludeDirectory ("~/Content/css/", "*.css") );


        }
    }
}
```

I have also this line in my `Global.asax.cs Application_Start()`

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Now when launching the server, the page loads fine but the css is not accessible.

In source code it is included like this:

```
<link href="/bundle/bootstrap?v=yW6L0KJ49BsmpuPPWZ1xvWLpXC5uk007PYbOr18eA2k1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

But my html is unable to use it and when I click on the link I get a:

```
System.Web.HttpException
The resource cannot be found.
```

With the folowing stack-trace:

```
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.Type controllerType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.String controllerName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit (System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext httpContext, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb, System.Object extraData) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Here is a picture of my project to see where the css files are located:

[image]

How do I get the `System.Web.Optimizations` to optimize and include my assets correctly?

Comment: Remove minified *.min.css stuff, it breaks bundle.

Comment: They where included with the Bootstrap package that was installed with MonoDevelop package handler. Would it be safe?

Comment: Absolutely, it's same CSS but...minified.

Comment: Okay removed all files from ~/Content and left only the ones in ~/Content/css. The problem still persists.

Comment: Adding BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false; made it work but it should work without it also when I want to minify my assets.

Comment: Yes, I removed them as sayd earlier. I now only have the bootstrap.css and bootstrap-theme.css. But the problem persists.

Comment: You may be running into this bug http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/105